# Random Number Issue Java

Tags: java, loops, random, numbers

So I have been searching everywhere for a way to do this and I can't find a method that would satisfy what my professor wants.

He wants us to create a random number with a random seed, that is then tested to see if it is a any number in a set of numbers, then change until it is any number that is not one of that set of numbers.

The catch is we are not allowed to use loops of any form other than if statements nor or allowed to use recursions in the process of doing this.

Please help.

Comment: I don't think he wants you find a method, but to write one. [hint hint]

Comment: Show us what you've tried, don't just ask for a solution.

Comment: Lmao thats what I meant, I've been sitting here for like 4 hours just stumped every idea I get seems to involve recursions or loops.

Comment: How big is the set of numbers?  What numeric range are you dealing with?  Are they integers?

Comment: @paddy
For the sake of the argument we want a basic random Number generator.

Random rand = new Random();
int m = rand.nextInt(10)

And m can only be say 9 or 7

Comment: `not allowed to use loops of any form other than if statements`---if statement is not a loop, so the qualification is meaningless.

Comment: @user3299002 For the sake of argument, there are simple and practical solutions to this in certain instances, which is why I asked a very specific question about how large the set of numbers is, their range, and their type.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good basic knowledge to remember for the future.

Comment: @Submersed ok going bring back some test lines of code I did, however most involved recursion until he told us that it was specifically out as well. 

I'm really kind of lost with this as a whole without using recursion or loops at all

Comment: Maybe he wants you to get used to using Java Collections?

Comment: Is it possible to provide an exact wording of the question? I suspect there is a misunderstanding somewhere.  Are the total set of numbers and and set of disallowed numbers provided?

Comment: @turbo sadly no this was an assignment spoken to us at the end of class today. There is no written documentation only what he verbally told us what we couldn't do to solve it.

Comment: The question doesn't actually include a question. Please make the necessary edits to add a question.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray I am simply looking for a way to do exactly what I stated, since I have absolutely no idea how to do it and there is no physical copy of the question only something he told us to work on at the end of class today to help us prepare for our exam on Thursday. I am just looking for a way to do exactly what my post says.

Comment: @user3299002 Then you should at the very least form it into a question. Nobody really needs to know if it's for an exam or to save the world, we just need to know the constraints (as arbitrary as they may be) and the requirements, in addition to your attempts and failures. You got most of that, which is great! But I figured that I would mention that since this is a Q&A website, questions usually get answers. Simply stating you need to do something without showing how you've failed so far and adding no code, is more of a code request than a question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solution does not use a single loop and it gives you results you wanted. Sorry about previous false solution. Try it out:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class rndNumberGenerator {

    public static int[] myNumbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        checkNumber1();    

    }

    public static void checkNumber1() {

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int x = rnd.nextInt(10);

        int y = goThroughAnArray1(0, x);

        if (y != -1) {
            System.out.println("Generated number is " + x + " and it's already part of the array."
                   + "\nGenerating new random number..");
           checkNumber2();
        }

        System.out.println("Generated number is " + x + " and it's not the part of the array.");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void checkNumber2() {

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int x = rnd.nextInt(10);

        int y = goThroughAnArray1(0, x);

        if (y != -1) {
            System.out.println("Generated number is " + x + " and it's already part of the array."
                   + "\nGenerating new random number..");
           checkNumber1();
        }

        System.out.println("Generated number is " + x + " and it's not the part of the array.");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static int goThroughAnArray1(int i, int number) {

        if (i == myNumbers.length)
            return -1;

        if (myNumbers[i] == number)
            return number;

        i++;
        int x = goThroughAnArray2(i, number);

        return x;
    }

    public static int goThroughAnArray2(int i, int number) {

        if (i == myNumbers.length)
            return -1;

        if (myNumbers[i] == number)
            return number;

        i++;
        int x = goThroughAnArray1(i, number);

        return x;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok this definitely works, currently trying to figure it out and break it down in my head, Thank you!

Comment: No problem, However would you mind explaining to me how the i++ in goThroughAnArray works.

Comment: This is ridiculous.  Not only is the code over-complicated and confusing, but the question stated that there are to be no loops or recursion.  This answer uses recursion, but the fact you used two functions for it instead of one shows that you don't understand what recursion is.

Comment: LOL!  I don't care about rep.  I am trying to point out that your answer, once again, does not answer the question.  It is a recursive solution, and not even a good one.

Comment: @paddy I see both of your points here, his method does use recursion without really using recursion, but it is the only solution I have found that is any semblance of being technically correct.

Comment: @msmolcic92 That is called *mutual recursion*, which is a form of recursion.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The question clearly stated "without using recursion".  Hiding the recursion by breaking into two pieces doesn't make it any less recursion.  The OP was wrong to accept this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the exercise is forcing you to adopt a programmer's thought process.  The problem is specified in terms of numbers that are not allowed.  However, testing and re-rolling forces you to use looping.

You need to flip your mindset and consider using a set of allowed numbers.  All you need to do is generate a random index into the 'allowed' set, and select the value at that position.

Comment: Holy crap you just gave me an idea. I've been so stuck on what isn't allowed I forgot to consider what exactly would be allowed.

Comment: The purpose of the exercise, as I say, is probably to make you think like a programmer instead of a sheep.

Comment: Ok now I have a new idea to run with on this. Thank you.

Comment: This works only with certain assumptions about the actual assigment, such as that the set of forbidden numbers is known in advance. This is not specified in the question: if you just have "a set of numbers" which are forbidden, this can't work without a loop/recursion somewhere.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I tried to get clarification about that in the comments, and found it a fruitless exercise.

Comment: Basically, you reconstructed the actual assignment from the assumption that it is doable :)

Comment: essentially he did, and I explained somewhat but I was also only given the vaguest of instructions on this assignment. But he did give me a slight idea of how to solve it without using recursions or loops even if the actual numbers in the set are still unknown.

Comment: This is a truly inspired solution, and I think it's the only way of solving this within the constraints of the question.